# Add quicklink to in the Admin posts page where I can query by a meta_key

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, admin, query

I have a Custom field `is-active` created with Advanced Custom Fields (ACF). I would like to add a quick link after the *All posts | Published | Trashed* etc links which filters all posts that have the value of `true` for the `is-active` meta key.

I successfully added the *Active* quick link to the list with this function:

```
add_filter('views_edit-ground_catalog', 'ground_add_admin_quick_link');
function ground_add_admin_quick_link($views) {

    if( ( is_admin() ) && ( $_GET['post_type'] == 'ground_catalog' ) ) {

     global $wp_query;
     unset($views['mine']);
     $args =  array(
        'post_type' => 'ground_catalog',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'meta_key'      => 'is-active',
        'meta_value'    => true,
        );


     $result = new WP_Query($args);

     $views['publish_f'] = sprintf('<a href="%s">Attivi<span class="count">(%d)</span></a>', admin_url('edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=ground_catalog&active=true'), $result->found_posts);

     return $views;

 }
```

Code for the query variables:

```
  function register_active() {
      global $wp;
      $wp->add_query_var( 'active' );
  }
  add_action( 'init', 'register_active' );

  function map_active( $wp_query ) {
      if ( $meta_value = $wp_query->get( 'active' ) ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'meta_key', 'is-active' );
        $wp_query->set( 'meta_value', $meta_value );
      }
  }
add_action( 'parse_query', 'map_active' );
```

When I inspect the query, all variables are set correctly

```
Query's variables:
active  true
meta_key    is-active
meta_value  true
```

But, the filter is not showing any posts. What am I missing?

All I need is a link `edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=ground_catalog&meta_key=is-active&meta_value=true`

Comment: Have you tried the `pre_get_posts` filter? Is `active` a valid and unused query var that you've whitelisted that isn't used elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Setup

I was able to reproduce the issue after creating a post type named `ground_catalog` with support for custom fields, then creating some test posts. I added the custom field `is-active` (using standard WordPress functionality) and entered the value `true` for some posts.

### The Fix

I was able to get the filter working by changing the arguments to `WP_Query`:

```
$result = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type'  => $post_type,
    'orderby'    => 'date',
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'meta_key'   => 'is-active',
    'meta_value' => 'true', // Note that this is a STRING
] );
```

### Full Example

Here is the full working code example, which contains some refactoring for readability as well as a fix for styling the current filter item and other minor changes:

```
add_filter( 'views_edit-ground_catalog', 'wpse246143_add_admin_quick_link' );
function wpse246143_add_admin_quick_link( $views ) {
    $post_type = 'ground_catalog';

    // Bail immediately if we're not looking at the right post type.
    if ( ! isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) || $post_type !== $_GET['post_type'] ) {
        return $views;
    }

    // Handle the class applied to the link filter.
    $link_class = false;
    if ( isset( $_GET['active'] ) && 'true' === $_GET['active'] ) {
        $link_class = 'current';
    }

    // Set up a query to determine how many posts are set up as is-active == true
    $result = new WP_Query( [
        'post_type'  => $post_type,
        'orderby'    => 'date',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
        'meta_key'   => 'is-active',
        'meta_value' => 'true',
    ] );

    // Generate the link for our filter. 
    // post_status=publish was removed to prevent a styling conflict with the existing 'Published' filter.
    $views['ground_catalog_active'] = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="%s">%s<span class="count">(%d)</span></a>',
            admin_url( "edit.php?post_type={$post_type}&active=true" ),
            $link_class,
            __( 'Attivi', 'text-domain' ),
            $result->found_posts
    );

    return $views;
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse246143_register_active' );
function wpse246143_register_active() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var( 'active' );
}

add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpse246143_map_active' );
function wpse246143_map_active( $wp_query ) {
    $meta_value = $wp_query->get( 'active' );

    if ( true == $meta_value ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'meta_key', 'is-active' );
        $wp_query->set( 'meta_value', $meta_value );
    }
}
```

### Post type registration and custom columns

For the sake of completeness and troubleshooting, here is the code that registers the `ground_catalog` post type as well as the addition and display of the `is-active` meta column.

```
// Register ground_catalog post type
add_action( 'init', 'wpse246143_register_ground_catalog' );
function wpse246143_register_ground_catalog() {
    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( 'Ground Catalogs', 'your_text_domain' ),
        "singular_name" => __( 'Ground Catalog', 'your_text_domain' ),
        );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( 'Ground Catalogs', 'your_text_domain' ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "ground_catalog", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,

        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "custom-fields" ),                 );

    register_post_type( "ground_catalog", $args );
}

// Add custom column to ground_catalog post list
add_filter( 'manage_ground_catalog_posts_columns' , 'wpse246143_manage_ground_catalog_columns' );
function wpse246143_manage_ground_catalog_columns( $columns ) {
    return array_merge( $columns, 
        array( 'is-active' => __( 'Is Active', 'your_text_domain' ) ) );
}

// Display custom column values on ground_catalog post list
add_action( 'manage_ground_catalog_posts_custom_column' , 'wpse246143_ground_catalog_custom_column', 10, 2 );
function wpse246143_ground_catalog_custom_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'is-active':
            $active = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'is-active', true );
            echo '<strong>is-active: </strong>';
            var_dump( $active );
            break;
    }
}
```

### Demos

I added some `ground_post` entries for troubleshooting and testing purposes. The custom columns show what has been entered for the `is-active` meta value. The only posts that will show up under the **Active** (Attivi) sort column are *Ground with just dirt* and *Ground with leaves on it*, because they are the only ones that have the `is-active` meta key set up with the value of `true` (string):

[image: ground_post list]

## Sorting in action

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but It is not working right now, can't think of any reason why it wouldn't.
Did it work for you straight away?

Comment: Sure! Yes, the code I posted has been fully tested and works for me. I have added some additional code for the post type registration and custom columns (for troubleshooting purposes) as well as a demo image and gif. I suspect that the issue is related to how your meta data is being stored for `is-active` or some issue related to how ACF is handling things.

Comment: Finally made it work!
For some reasons it didnt like "active=true" as per your example, but all i had to do is "active=1"

Comment: Great! Thank you for reporting back with the details.